# What does the report in "block and report" do?

Tags: calls, call-screening, spam

In the August Marshmallow 6.0.1 update, there appears to be a new feature called "block and report", which is triggered for some new calls. In this case, it was actually spam. Blocking adds the number to the phone application block list. What does the report do?

[image: spam call]

I normally file call complaints with [FTC Do Not Call Registry](https://www.donotcall.gov/default.aspx). Does report do this for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Report" does what it says, report the phone number as spam *to Google*. This will help users of Google's caller ID (e.g. Nexus device users) in the future, since number reported as spam will be shown as "Suspected spam caller" or "Spam" as caller ID.

From [Nexus official support](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3459196),

> #### Mark calls as spam
>
> You can mark all calls from a number as spam to keep from getting any more and report the spammer.
>
> **Spam detection**
>
> If you see "Suspected spam caller" or "Spam" as the caller ID, the call might be spam. You can answer the call, or block and report the number.

---

> I normally file call complaints with FTC Do Not Call Registry. Does *Report* do this for me?

I believe no, because DNC is country-dependent (e.g. FTC's National DNC Registry in US), and I've never heard Google working together with these kinds of government instance.

Comment: Actually it looks like Google is now working with government agencies, at least in the US: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-robocalls-idUSKCN10U18L